# Структуры. База данных товаров

Tags: c++

В этой программе я определяю общую стоимость (по цене поставки) просроченных товаров в целом, но задача стоит в том, чтобы определять эту стоимость отдельно по каждому отделу, я догадываюсь, что нужно сделать ещё одну структуру, но уже для отделов, но как реализовать не знаю.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct item
{
public:

    string name;
    int kol;
    double pricepost,pricetov;
    string otdel;
    int data;
}market[20];

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int i, n, j = 1;
int a=2021;
double prosr=0;
double ideal=0;
double prosr2=0;
int k=0;
    cout << "Введите количество разных товаров на складе: " << endl;
    (cin >> n).get();

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите название " << j++ << " товара: " << endl;
        getline(cin,market[i].name);
    }
    for (j = 1, i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите количество " << j++ << " товара на складе в килограммах: " << endl;
        cin >> market[i].kol;
    }
    for (j = 1, i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите цену продажи " << j++ << " товара в гривнах: " << endl;
        cin >> market[i].pricetov;
    }
    for (j = 1, i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите цену поставки " << j++ << " товара в гривнах: " << endl;
        cin >> market[i].pricepost;
    }
    for (j = 1,i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите дату поступления " << j++ << " товара на склад: " << endl;
        cin>>market[i].data;
    }
    for (j = 1,i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите отдел " << j++ << " товара: " << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,market[i].otdel);

    }
for (j = 1,i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
if (market[i].data<a)
{
prosr=prosr+market[i].pricepost*market[i].kol; //считаем убытки(поставки) от просрочки
prosr2=prosr2+market[i].pricetov*market[i].kol; //считаем теоретическую прибыль именно продажи товаров
k=k+1;
}
    }
for (j = 1,i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
ideal=prosr2+(market[i].pricetov*(n-k)); // теоретическая прибыль с продажи просрочки+продажа обычных товаров
    }
    cout<<"Убытки от просроченных товаров равны "<<prosr<<" гривен";
   cout<<"Выручка без просроченных товаров могла быть "<<ideal<<" гривен";
}
```

Comment: Как вариант(не самый правильный, думаю) - можно в эту структуру добавить поле, указывающее отдел, к которому относится товар, и при расчете стоимости просрочки в одном цикле считать отдельные суммы для всех отделов сразу.

Comment: В базах данных это делается просто. Создаётся массив отделов. А у товаров только указател(ь/и) на отдел(ы).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логику программы почти не менял, хотя в некоторых моментах мне она показалась странной. Постарался расписать все новое, что добавил в комментариях.

Так же хотелось бы сказать, что я писал код под стать вашему, хотя **максимально рекомендую** придумывать названия переменным, полям и т.д. более понятные. Например не `kol`, а `count`, не `pricetov`, а или `price` (т.к. это поле и так в структуре `item` что уже говорит, что это цена товара) или `price_product`. Еще например не повторять по нескольку раз одни и те же циклы, а вынести ввод информации о товаре в функцию (как я и сделал) (Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1232753/%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89/1232799#1232799) кода как лучше не писать, как минимум, чтобы вам быстрей помогли)

Вот пример кода с комментариями:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Структура отдела
struct Otdel {
public:
    //Название
    string name;
    //На поставку
    int prosr;
    //На просрочке
    int prosr2;
    //Без просрочки можно
    int ideal;
} otdels[20];

struct item
{
public:
    string name;
    int kol;
    double pricepost, pricetov;
    //Указатель на отдел
    Otdel* otdel;
    int data;
} market[20];

//Функция ввода предмета market[index] 
void inputItem(int index) {
    cout << "Введите название " << index + 1 << " товара: " << endl;
    getline(cin, market[index].name);
    cout << "Введите количество " << index + 1 << " товара на складе в килограммах: " << endl;
    cin >> market[index].kol;
    cout << "Введите цену продажи " << index + 1 << " товара в гривнах: " << endl;
    cin >> market[index].pricetov;
    cout << "Введите цену поставки " << index + 1 << " товара в гривнах: " << endl;
    cin >> market[index].pricepost;
    cout << "Введите дату поступления " << index + 1 << " товара на склад: " << endl;
    cin >> market[index].data;
}

//Функия, которая ищет в otdels отдел с названием value
//если он есть то возвращает указатель на него
Otdel* find(int count, string& value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        if (otdels[i].name == value)
            return &otdels[i];
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    //Нужно для ввода и вывода русских символов
    //при setlocale введенное название товара на русском отображается не корректно
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    //m - кол-во отделов
    int i, n, j = 1, m;
    int a = 2021;
    cout << "Введите количество разных товаров на складе: " << endl;
    (cin >> n).get();

    for (i = 0, m = 0; i < n; i++) {
        //Сначала основные данные о товаре
        inputItem(i);
        //Теперь информацию об отделе товара
        cout << "Введите отдел " << i + 1 << " товара: " << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        string otdel;
        getline(cin, otdel);
        //Находим отдел с названием otdel
        Otdel* ot = find(m, otdel);
        //Если не нашли (и добавил проверку на кол-во отделов)
        if (ot == nullptr && m <= 20) {
            //то присваиваем новому отделу название otdel
            otdels[m].name = otdel;
            //инициализируем остальные поля, как 0
            otdels[m].prosr = 0, otdels[m].prosr2 = 0, otdels[m].ideal = 0;
            //ot устанавливаем указатель на новый отдел увеличивая их кол-во
            ot = &otdels[m++];
        }
        //Присваиваем товару отдел
        market[i].otdel = ot;
    }

    for (j = 1, i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //Если товар просрочен
        if (market[i].data < a)
        {
            //Находим расходы на поставку
            market[i].otdel->prosr += market[i].pricepost * market[i].kol;
            //Расходы от просрочки
            market[i].otdel->prosr2 += market[i].pricetov * market[i].kol;
        }
        //Сразу высчитываем сколько всего можно было заработать денег
        market[i].otdel->ideal += market[i].pricetov * market[i].kol;
    }

    //Ну и выводим
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cout << "Отдел: " << otdels[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Убытки от просроченных товаров равны " << otdels[i].prosr2 << " гривен" << endl;
        cout << "Выручка без просроченных товаров могла быть " << otdels[i].ideal << " гривен" << endl;
    }
}
```

Идея думаю понятна. У нас есть отделы и каждый товар указывает на свой отдел.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @human пожалуйста если вам помог мой ответ, то выберите его как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа.